# SparkContext.loadFromMapRDB with generic type

Tags: scala, generics

```
def loadFromMapR[T: Manifest](path: String): RDD[T] = {
   val selectedTable = sc.loadFromMapRDB[T](path)
    selectedTable }
```

I am working in Scala and want to allow a generic type to be loaded from a SparkContext.  This code will work if I specify the type as such.

```
def loadFromMapR(path: String): RDD[basicObject] = {
  val selectedTable = sc.loadFromMapRDB[basicObject](path)
  selectedTable }
```

But I want to make it generic! My first code doesn't compile! I am getting an error that states:

```
not enough arguments for method loadFromMapRDB (implicit evidence $1: Scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])
could not find implicit value for parameter f: com.mapr.db.spark.RDD.RDDTYPE[T]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `: RDDTYPE` to the definition of `T`:

```
def loadFromMapR[T: ClassTag : RDDTYPE](path: String): RDD[T] = {
  sc.loadFromMapRDB[T](path)
}
```

[note: `Manifest` is deprecated, so I replaced it with `ClassTag`]

This is of course shorthand for:

```
def loadFromMapR[T](path: String)(implicit ev1: ClassTag[T], ev2: RDDTYPE[T]): RDD[T] = {
  sc.loadFromMapRDB[T](path)
}
```

Which means - our function expects implicit parameters of types `ClassTag[T]` and `RDDTYPE[T]`, both are necessary when calling `loadFromMapRDB` which expects such implicit parameters - as can be seen in its signature:

```
def loadFromMapRDB[T](tableName: String)(implicit 
  evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T], 
  e: DefaultType[T, OJAIDocument], 
  f: RDDTYPE[T]
): MapRDBTableScanRDD[T]
```